# Tab not opening dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, keyboard-events, keydown

I'm unable to 'open' drop down menu on keydown of 'tab' key. The 'open's display: block is not firing off .. only able to tab through main 'top' menu items, none of the sub-menu li items. Please help. HTML, Jquery, and 'open' for CSS is below.

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <div class="menu-primary-navigation-container">
        <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1833" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-1833">
                <a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1835" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1835"><a href="?page_id=6&#038;quicksearch=true&#038;officeid=1159">Our Listings</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/island-listings/">Island Listings</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2059" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2059">
                <a>Rentals</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-739"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/home/management-team/">Management Team</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/long-term-rentals/">Long Term Rentals</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1433" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1433"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/vacation-rentals/">Vacation Rentals</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1559" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1559"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/property-management/">Property Management</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-2086" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2086">
                <a>About Us</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/our-agents/">Meet Our Agents</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/our-testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/mission-and-vision/">Mission and Vision</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2105"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/community-service/">Community Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-2087" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2087">
                <a>Island Living</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/island-living/">Island Information</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/big-island-maps/">Hawai&#8217;i Island Maps</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/island-links/">Island Links</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1932"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/communities/">Communities</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1994" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1994">
                <a>Resources</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-2721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2721"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/blog-posts/">Blog Posts</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1931"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com/preferred-vendors/">Preferred Vendors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-1729">
                <a>Translate</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1824" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-1824"><a href="http://lavarockrealty.com">English</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1730"><a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A//lavarockrealty.com/&#038;sl=en&#038;tl=zh-CN">Chinese (simplified)</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1936" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1936"><a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&#038;sl=en&#038;tl=zh-TW&#038;u=http%3A%2F%2Flavarockrealty.com%2F&#038;sandbox=1">Chinese (traditional)</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1731" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1731"><a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&#038;sl=en&#038;tl=ja&#038;u=http%3A%2F%2Flavarockrealty.com%2F&#038;sandbox=1">Japanese</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a:not([href]').each(function() {
    $('a:not([href]').attr('tabindex', '0');
});
$('ul#menu-primary-navigation > li').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        var topMenu = $(this).next('li');
        var subMenu = $(this).next('li > ul.sub-menu');

        topMenu.addClass('ada-outline');
        subMenu.addClass('open');
        console.log('subMenu', subMenu);
    }
});
.open{display: block;}
```

Comment: recently added the additional 'if' conditional .. all dropdown menus open however on first 'tab', where instead, I'd like the 'current' ul.sub-menu to open ... $('ul#menu-primary-navigation > li').keydown(function(e) {
   

                if($(this).parent('li').is(':last-child:not(".menu > li > a")')){
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('.openSubMenu').removeClass('openSubMenu');
                }  @pindo very similar to the example you helped me with ..

Comment: if($(this).parent('ul').is(':last-child:not("ul#menu-primary-navigation>li>a")')){ 
                    console.log($(this).parent('ul'));                   
                    $(this).parent('ul').parent('.openSubMenu').removeClass('openSubMenu');
                } //got drop downs to open one-by-one on 'tab' unable to removeClass (which is probably because style is "display: block !important"?) or add css of display:none !important, I also tried attr() .. help?

Comment: reformat html and javascript